# Formal comparison of two mediation effects

Tags: effect-size, model-comparison, mediation

Is there a method to statistically compare two mediation effects, given the same IV and DV? We have two different mediators and we want to compare the resulting models, as in:

Model 1: $X – M_{1} – Y$

Model 2: $X – M_{2} - Y$

Our question is, is the indirect effect of the IV ($X$) on the DV ($Y$) that goes through $M_{1}$ significantly different than the indirect effect of the IV ($X$) on the DV ($Y$)  that goes through $M_{2}$?